# importance of IDE when developing enterprise application

Tags: visual-studio, ide, netbeans

what is the importance of the IDE(Integrated development environment) when we develop enterprise applications.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IDE brings together a number of different applications that are needed for rapid development, some IDEs provide more facilities than others.

- Text/Code editor
- Compiler integration
- Debugger integration
- Code completion/snippets
- GUI editor
- Test suite integration
- Source control integration

This is important not only for enterprise application development, but is useful for a single developer as well.

Comment: ::yep..thnx for your quick reply..and as I know IDE is playing major role for utilizing frameworks.I want to know about much details for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends" - on the people, the environment, languages and culture.

[The IDE Divide](http://osteele.com/archives/2004/11/ides)

I use Vim and the OS is my IDE: Linux is "integrated" enough, and I can swap any component I want when I find better ones.

But I suppose this is true only for some definition of "enterprise". Some might say I'll never write a real enterprise-y application, and I'm fine with that.